# How to convert array format but non-array data into an array in PHP?

Tags: php

```
$details = {"success":true,"user":{"id":"10018","username":"goyal"}};
```

here u can see that, "$details" looks like an array, but in reality it is not an array. 
whenever i type:

```
echo $details;
```

i got full details on screen like:

```
{"success":true,"user":{"id":"10018","username":"goyal"}}
```

but whenever i try to get specific details like only 'username' or 'id' using
echo command, it doesn't show anything because it is not an array.
So how to convert this plain array looking data into an array?
please give me full script.

Comment: Look at json_decode ;)

Comment: And look at jsons manual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use json_decode() function like that

```
$detail=json_decode($details);
echo $details->user->username;//result  :- goyal
echo $details->success;//result  :- true
echo $details->user->id;//result  :- 10018
```

Comment: Because `json_decode` here is returning `Object` not `Array` so `$data->success` will work instead of `$detail['success']`. Have you tried your code?

Comment: Since i am the beginner, I have chosen ur answer, because it is very simple and working great. Thank you so much sir, and thanks to all of you for your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [**json_decode()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

> Takes a JSON encoded string and converts it into a PHP variable.

PHP snippet:

```
$data = json_decode('{"success":true,"user":{"id":"10018","username":"goyal"}}');
print_r($data);
```

Will return object and give you output:

```
stdClass Object ( [success] => 1 [user] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 10018 [username] => goyal ) )
```

If you want to print individual property then try:

```
echo $data->success;
```

Answer (score 0):

to get back an associative array place true as second paramnter of json_decode like

```
$detail = json_decode($details, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function

```
$details = '{"success":true,"user":{"id":"10018","username":"goyal"}}';
$details = json_decode($details);
echo $details->user->username;
```

[code at pastebin](http://pastebin.com/x7BB3ytD)